# search & replace elements of a list into a string iteratively into a new file using python

Tags: python, list, scripting

I have been trying to write a script to read the contents of file1 & replace a "specific string" (rabbit) with elements of a list (iteratively using for loop) that I have created in earlier part of the program and write the contents to a new file (file2).

In the below code "new_list" is a list created from the contents of file1. so the problem I am facing here is as I am using for loop, all the contents of file1 are written to file2 multiple times (# of elements in the list). But I am interested in just replacing "rabbit" string/line with list elements (iteratively with out touching other lines/strings) & write it to a newfile/file2. Could anyone please help me here to find the right solution?

```
file1  = open(filename, 'r')
file2 = open('newfile', 'r+')
for line in file1:
 for s in new_list:
       animal = line.replace('rabbit', s )
       file2.write(animal)
file1.close()
file2.close()
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want to do. Let's say `new_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'horse']`. Do you want each occurrence of 'rabbit' in file1 to be replaced by 'cat dog horse'? **OR** Do you want the 1st occurrence of 'rabbit' to be replace by 'cat'; the 2nd 'rabbit' gets replaced by 'dog'; the 3rd 'rabbit' gets replaced by 'horse'? Or something else...?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its because of your loops order , change it to :

```
for s in new_list:
   for line in file1:
     try:  
       line = line.replace('rabbit', s )
       file2.write(line)
     except:
       continue
```

Comment: I tried exactly what you mentioned above....but now the output is little weird, basically only first element of the list is replaced with "rabbit" & the reset of the elements are ignored. And after parsing half of the file, it started writing the contents of the file multiple times. ( as # of elements of the list)

Answer (score 0):

You can  use  `str.join` to write the contents of the list, replace will only change that lines the `rabbit` appears in so there is absolutely no need for a `try/except`

```
 with open(filename, 'r') as file1,open('newfile', 'w') as file2:
    for line in file1:
       line = line.replace('rabbit', " ".join(new_list) )
       file2.write(line)
```

Comment: Your inputs are useful, but I am trying to write the elements of the list to next line (& so on) not join to the same line.

Comment: if you are using `line.replace('rabbit', s )` how do you expect to not write to the same line?